# Malloc and unaligned memory

Tags: c, malloc

malloc() documentation says that the returned pointer is suitably aligned for any kind of variable. On my system, a long double has size 12, however some pointers returned by malloc() are aligned on 8 byte boundary and not 12. (ptr % 12 gives 4). Can anybody point out what am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you read about malloc returning aligned memory?

Comment: In the man page. See here under return value http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc. Or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: 12 byte long doubles don't require 12 byte alignment.

Comment: @user44990 No, you aren't necessarily misinterpreting anything. I just didn't know this and didn't find it with a quick search.

Comment: The posix_memalign manpage mentions that glibc always returns 8 byte aligned addresses, so maybe that is happening here. Does anyone know if the general statement mentioned in the man page holds for any other system?

Comment: What system has a 12 byte long double?

Comment: I have a core i3 cpu and running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You're confusing size and alignment. Check `alignof(long double)`. And think of `int[1000]`...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: x86? 80-bit x87 floating-point values padded to the closest word multiple

Comment: Alignment restrictions have their origin in CPU bus logic design.  Without going into the technical details, you will only see powers of 2.  12 not being a power of 2 can't be an alignment size.

Comment: @Christoph The size of 8087 80 bit type is 10 rather than 12.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: is there any C compiler that agrees with that? Quote from the *Intel C++ Compiler User and Reference Guides* on the size of `long double`: *its size must be a multiple of its alignment*, which is necessary so arrays can satisfy `sizeof` semantics required by the C standard and still correctly align its fields

Answer (score 5):

Evidently, `long double` need not be aligned to 12 bytes. On systems such as yours, the largest alignment for a primitive C type is 8 bytes for `double`. Don't confuse alignment and size - while many smaller (especially primitive) types must be naturally aligned - that is, aligned to their own size - this is prohibitive for larger data types (think fragmentation) and doesn't make anything easier for the hardware.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: `struct`s.

Comment: @MatteoItalia ... but the first member of a struct must be suitable aligned or undefined behaviour occurs. That makes no sense. Did you know it's possible to turn on bus error checking on Intel machines? Perhaps you should verify this before you make assertions...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour `long double` for starters. A `struct`'s members must of course be suitably aligned (not sure if only the first one or all of them), but the structure as a whole doesn't have further alignment requirements. Imagine if `struct IntHashSet { uint32_t used; uint32_t capacity; int32_t *table; int32_t smalltable[60 / 4]; }` needed 72 byte alignment.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: of course, as I know that a `struct` may contain padding to align its other members suitably; but the point that @delnan is probably trying to make is that a type may have different alignment requirements than its whole size. Also, nobody will ever enable alignment checks on Intel platforms since 20+ years of forgiveness led to binaries that would just die in flames whenever strict alignment requirements were enabled (e.g. using 1-byte packed `struct`s read from a file is common, and I don't think compilers ever bothered to generate code to fix those accesses on x86).

Comment: The representation of struct members is irrelevant. "All
pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other."

Comment: @MatteoItalia Actually, I would enable alignment checks to highlight the parts of my code that could be drastically sped up by using the *correct* alignment, as well as the portability improvement.

Comment: @MatteoItalia not respecting alignment on Intel processor will typically not make your program crash but it will makes your program run slower

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: the quote about 'pointers to structures' is precisely about the pointers, not about the structures that they point at.  There are parts of your comments that are on target; there typically aren't built-in types bigger than `long double` (though pointers on some esoteric machines can be bigger — IBM AS/400 and derivatives, I believe).  Any particular struct normally has the alignment of its most stringently aligned member; within the structure, the members are individually properly aligned (that's why you can get holes).

Comment: Another example - on Linux i686, `long long` has size 8 and alignment 4.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: any decent C compiler won't emit code that works on unaligned data unless you go for it explicitly (using nonstandard pragmas to fiddle with `struct` packing, or doing strange stuff like taking the middle of a `char` array and casting the pointer to some other pointer data type). I admit it can be useful when using data structures from other libraries, but for your own code typically working on unaligned data is an explicit choice. @ouah: I know, that's one of the things you pick up in years of reading Raymond Chen's blog. :)

Answer (score 4):

On `gcc` for Linux and `x86` you have:

`sizeof (long double) == 12`

and

on `gcc` for Linux and `x64` you have:

`sizeof (long double) == 16`

The ABI alignment requirements for `x64` `long double` is `16`-bytes. For `x86`, no type requires more than `8`-bytes of alignment.

To respect that `glibc` `malloc` returns memory object aligned with `8`-bytes on `32-bit` system and aligned on `16`-bytes for `64`-bit systems.

From `glibc` doc:

> The block that malloc gives you is guaranteed to be aligned so that it can hold any type of data. On GNU systems, the address is always a multiple of eight on most systems, and a multiple of 16 on 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 3):

On any sane cpu architecture, the largest possible alignment requirement for an object of size 12 is 4. The alignment requirement must be a power of 2 that divides the size of the type evenly. Indeed this gives very poor alignment (objects spanning cache lines or even pages!), which is why the x86_64 ABI changed the size of `long double` to 16: so that it would be possible to align it not to cross any boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` will return memory properly aligned for any type, because typically the pointer it returns is converted to a pointer of an arbitrary type and such conversion is typically (read: infinitely close to 100% of the time) a no-op. For any architecture and compiler the maximum alignment of any type is however a constant and typically it is the maximum of the alignment of all primitive types. The size of an object should however be a multiple of its alignment. Sometimes this requirement must be met by adding padding to the value inside the object.

If your compiler is modern enough it will support `_Alignof`, similar to `sizeof`, so you can check the actual alignment with a small program. I think on your architecture the maximum alignment is 4. If `malloc` always returns addresses aligned by 8, then it still complies. It is not unusual for `malloc` to meet an alignment that is a multiple of the maximum alignment of the types.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing that while a type's size must be a multiple of its alignment (which is restricted by the actual hardware), they need not be equal.

In case of `long double`, this translates to

```
_Alignof (long double) == 4
sizeof (long double) == 12
```

with gcc/x86 and

```
_Alignof (long double) == 16
sizeof (long double) == 16
```

with gcc/x64, where in both cases `long double` has 80-bit extended precision.

If we were not restricted by alignment, most naturally we'd end up with

```
sizeof (long double) == 10
```

In the presence of alignment, we'd either have to go with an alignment of 2 (which we don't for efficiency reasons), or introduce padding to arrays so elements align correctly. This violates C language semantics were an array's size is the product of its element size and count.